# how not to open new window on clicks after first click on link <a href="abc.jsp" target="_blank">,

Tags: javascript, html

I need to open a new window on first click on link .

But not to open a new windows on clicks on same link after first click.

Is there any way to solve this problem through html or javascript.

Thanks
Jyoti

Comment: why have you annotated your your question with JAVA tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
var check=0;
function lanuchWindow(page){
  if(check==0){
    OpenWin = this.open(page);
    check=1;
  }
}
</script>
```

html code to call script:

```
<a href="#" onclick='lanuchWindow('pageURL.htm')'>;Launch Window</a>
```

This might probably help you... It will launch window for 1st time and set it's variable check to 1 and when again the link is clicked condition turns false and hence no window is launched.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I need to focus on further clicks. I my using ---- OpenWin.focus();.  This is working in IE but not in mozilla. Is there any solution to focus on further clicks.

Answer (score 7):

Replace '_blank' with another string, e.g. 'new_window' (don't use spaces)

On further clicks the link will be opened inside the window opened onto the first click.

See (4.) inside the specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.3.2

Comment: Thanks for reply. Its working. Now on further clicks, link is opening on same old window . Is there any way to focus on window opened onto the first click?

Comment: do you have access to the pages loaded inside the window?

Comment: I have not used spaces. But on further clicks the focus is not coming. Could you please tell me how can i focus on same old window on further clicks.

Comment: The easiest way is to put into all pages that can be load inside the popup the following javascript-instruction: `window.focus()` But it will depend on user-settings, if this will work at all, because the user can prevent pages from stealing the focus.

Answer (score 1):

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> 
<!-- Begin 
function Launch(page) { 
OpenWin = this.open(page, "mywin", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,width=550,height=250"); 
} 
// End --> 
</SCRIPT> 


<a href="#" onClick="Launch(...)">click</a>
```

*NOTICE: it won't work if the JS is disabled on Browser. thanks four ur reply, Andy E*

Comment: What happens when a user visits the page with JS disabled?  None of those links will work for him.

Comment: it is an alternative solution of the question. It won't work if the JS is disabled on Browser. But, the author wanted to know JS variation also.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="foo" href="url" target="_blank">hello</a>
<script>
    // add an onclick handler:
    $("#foo").click(function(){
        // Now remove the onclick handler so subsequent clicks don't fire it.
        $(this).click(function(){});

        // And set the target attribute so it opens in current window...
        $(this).attr("target", "");

        return true;
    });
</script>
```

This is a better option than the ones listed above because it degrades nicely for people who don't have javascript, or want to use their middle mouse button to force opening in a new tab.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment above on Dr. Molle's post.  Thought you wanted the first click to pop up a new window and subsequent ones to open in the same window.  Thought it was a weird request, but was happy to oblige.  Voted Dr. Molle up instead.